# Count duplicated couple of lines

Tags: bash, vi

I have a configuration file with this format:

```
cod    11
loc1   23
pto1   33
loc2   55
pto2   66
cod    12
loc1   55
pto1   66
loc2   88
pto2   77
...
```

I want to count how many times a pair of numbers appear in sequence loc/pto (indipendently of loc/pto number). In the example, the couple 55/66 appears 2 times (once as loc1/pto1 and one as loc2/pto2).

I have googled around and tried some combination of `grep`, `uniq` and `awk` but I only managed in count single line or number duplicated. I read the `man` documentation of those commands not finding any clue relative to my problem.

Comment: I am writing a test unit for a C++ calss loading this file and I have to know this count for a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
$ sort file | uniq -f1 -dc
  2 loc1   55
  2 pto1   66
```

`-f1` is skipping the 1st field when comparing lines

`-dc` is printing duplicate line with its associated count

Comment: `pto1   66 pto2 66 != 2 pto1 66`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many times a duplicate number appeared in the file:

```
awk '{print $2}' <filename> | sort | uniq -dc
Output:
2 55
2 66
```

If you want to know how many times a number appeared in the file regardless of being duplicate or not:

```
awk '{print $2}' <filename> | sort | uniq -c
Output:
1 11
1 12
1 23
1 33
2 55
2 66
1 77
1 88
```

If you want to print the full line on duplicate match based on second column:

```
awk '{print $2}' <filename> | sort | uniq -d | grep -F -f - <filename>
Output:
loc2   55
pto2   66
loc1   55
pto1   66
```

Comment: I would like to count duplicate occurences of **couples** of numbers, not single numbers occurrences (because those numbers are meaningful only as pairs).

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi, ...but that's pretty obvious -- you have a string that has `2`s before each number that's paired. Filter for those, and there you are.

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi, ...if you want output that's more specific, then I suggest making your question specific enough that folks actually know the details.

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi, ...if you'd made it specific enough to comply with site rules ("I have input X, I want output Y, I tried Z but its output is A"), then it would be specific enough that you wouldn't have had any need to clarify later.

Answer (score 0):

Despite no visible effort on the part of the OP, this was an interesting question to work out.

```
awk '{for (i=1 ; i < 10 ; i++) if (NR == i) array[i]=$2} END {for (i=1 ; i < 10 ; i++) print array[i] "," array[i+1]}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Output-

```
  1 11,23
  1 12,55
  1 23,33
  1 33,55
  2 55,66
  1 66,12
  1 66,88
  1 88,
```

The output tells you that 55 is followed by 66 twice. Other pairs only occur once.

Explanation-

I define an array in `awk` whoe elements are the `i`th number in the second column. The part after the `END` concatenates the `i`th and `i+1`th element. Then there is a `sort | uniq -c` to see if these pairs occur more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it doeas not solve my problem as it does not count only duplicates of pair loc/pto but also pto1/loc2 or cod/loc that have no means (and the commnad output hides this inofrmation). Anyway I think I could try to modify your solution to reach my goal.

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi you did not mention those things in your question. How are people supposed to guess? Please read these- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"I want to count how many times a pair of numbers appear in sequence loc/pto (indipendently of loc/pto number)"*... I thought it was clear.

Comment: @MarcoStramezzi You need to put expected output into your question so that we can see if our code matches your requirement. Please take a moment and go through the links I posted in my earlier comment.